# How to compare an array to a number of arrays C#

Tags: c#, arrays, cycle

I need to compare one array containing pretty many strings

```
Array 1. {"Moscow", "Paris", "London", "Minsk", ... and so on} <br>
```

To some other arrays

```
Array 2. {"Moscow", "Barselona", "Sydney"} <br>
Array 3. {"Madrid", "Kiev", "London", "Minsk"}<br>
```

and others.

Then I need to display the matches and change some vars in the class.
Like this: display Moscow, London and Minsk.

And then, for example: 
We have class City and some cities there.

As we have Moscow in common, I need to do something, like this:

```
Moscow.var=&lt;some value&gt; <br>
```

How to do this faster?

UPD: Faster than comparing one array to the others one by one.

```
var array1 = new[] {"Moscow", "Paris", "London", "Minsk"};
var array2 = new [] {"Madrid", "Kiev", "London", "Minsk"};
for (int i = 0; i < Array1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int t = 0; t < array2.Length; t++)
                {
                    if (array1[i] == array2[t])
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
                        switch (i) {
                        case 0: 
                        Moscow.common=true;
                        break;
                        And cases here for all the possible i's
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
```

And the same for array1 and array3, array1 and array4

Comment: Faster than what? What is the “something” you need to do? Do you have some code that does this? You need to show it to us.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is not clear at all but if you want to find matches between two string arrays you can use `LINQ` something like

```
var array1 = new[] {"Moscow", "Paris", "London", "Minsk"};
var array2 = new [] {"Madrid", "Kiev", "London", "Minsk"};

var common= from ar1 in array1
            join ar2 in array2 on ar1 equals ar2
            select ar1;

//or 
var common2= array1.Join(array2, ar1 => ar1, ar2 => ar2, 
                        (ar1, ar2) => ar1);
```